# json parsing using GET method

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I just want to hit URL :http://kiascenehai.pk/rest_api/todayEvents/api-key/Of7NU7Jimh665D5G5VwO2eKO69sWv9lf/format/json
and parameter is city_id.i.e: /city_id/1
but; compiler creates Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" or error 300; so what shall be best way to pass arguments ?

Comment: Which language? Objective-C?

Comment: yes Gergo ..its ios (objective) C .

Comment: is your final url is like [**this**](http://kiascenehai.pk/rest_api/todayEvents/api-key/Of7NU7Jimh665D5G5VwO2eKO69sWv9lf/format/json?city_id=1)??

Comment: no fahim it gives some dictionaries in an array ...this is not the required output

Comment: It's less of a question of what is the "best way" to pass arguments than it is "in what format does that web service require the request be formatted." Some web services expect parameters to come in the form of JSON. Others POST requests with the parameters in the body of the request. Some GET requests with the parameters in the URL of the request. You need to get information from the web service provider regarding the API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get method in ios json parsing issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837006/get-method-in-ios-json-parsing-issue)