# get method in ios json parsing issue

Tags: ios, json, methods, get

I just want to hit URL :
http://kiascenehai.pk/rest_api/todayEvents/api-key/Of7NU7Jimh665D5G5VwO2eKO69sWv9lf/format/json
 and parameter is city_id.i.e: `/city_id/1` but; compiler creates Error

```
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002

 "unsupported URL"

 or
 error 300;
```

so what shall be best way to pass arguments in a method in objective c???it also causes Error `Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303` "The operation couldn’t be completed.

```
(kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303
```

It will be pleasure for me if any one can reply me fast as possible.

Comment: There is no issue with this url. Can you show your code ?

Comment: -(void)requestForEvents_cityId:(NSString*)cityid;
{
    NSString *API_URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://kiascenehai.pk/rest_api/todayEvents/api-key/Of7NU7Jimh665D5G5VwO2eKO69sWv9lf/format/json"];
    NSLog(@"i am here looking URL: %@", API_URL);
    self.httpWorker = [[HttpWorker alloc] init];
    [self.httpWorker setDelegate:[[Resources getResources] getEventsDataParser]];

Comment: NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString string];
    [str appendFormat:@"/city_id/%@",cityid];

    NSData * data  = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    [self.httpWorker requestPOSTNetwork:API_URL data:data];
    [self.httpWorker requestPOSTNetwork:str data:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to reproduce issue you have mentioned, Probably the issue 'll be not because of the URL or parameters you used.

This is one of the best way to handle GET web service call and parsing data from the response, here i implemented the web call with your URL and params,

```
// Server data fetch
- (void)getDataForCityId:(NSInteger)cityId
{
    NSMutableString *urlString = [@"http://kiascenehai.pk/rest_api/todayEvents/api-key/Of7NU7Jimh665D5G5VwO2eKO69sWv9lf/format/json/city_id/" mutableCopy];
    [urlString appendFormat:@"%d", cityId];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
     {
         if (data)
         {
             id jsonObj = [self parseJSON:data];
         }
     }];
}

// Method parses the JSON Data Received
- (id)parseJSON:(NSData *)data
{
    id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
    return jsonData;
}
```

The jsonObj parsed form the response is as[image]

Comment: Well thank you so much ;Alex Andrews your code really works.Again thanks buddy

Comment: @user3807662 Is there any problem for you with the screenshot i added in the answer? i can remove then.

Comment: no, it was just simple but i had to embed in my code as i got some idea from your code and then make string concatenation and it just works in my application.